# How to make a Function in C#?

Tags: c#

Do I make the methods correctly? Here is my Code?
I'm a newbie in C#. I search about creating methods but I don't know exactly where I should put inside my code.

```
namespace PierEstimator
{

    public double HypotenouseCalculation(double Num1, double Num2,double Hypotenouse)
    {
        Hypotenouse =  Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Num1, 2) + Math.Pow(Num2, 2));
    }


    public partial class FormPierEstimator : Form
    {
        double Length;

        public FormPierEstimator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PierTriangleComputation();
        }

        private void PierTriangleComputation()
        {
            double Length1, Length2;
            Length = Hypotenouse(Length1, Length2);
        }
    }
}
```

When I Call Hypotenouse, it is not functioning.

Comment: May I suggest that you find a C# beginner tutorial or a book?

Comment: What is `Hypotenouse`?

Comment: What does *not functioning* mean? Currently, your code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: All methods and functions must be within a class. Also returning a value use: `return Math.Sqrt(........);`  Also a `Form` class must be the first class in the file, else your designer will not work.

Comment: Hypotenouse is the result that I want to accomplish. Hypotenouse is the function that I want to call.

Comment: @DaveRyan Place HypotenouseCalculation method in the same class FormPierEstimator.

Call HypotenouseCalculation instead of Hypotenouse to get the result. Assign some values to Length1 and Length2 variables.

Rewrite HypotenouseCalculation to used the correct .NET libraries for the functions that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have added a function directly within the namespace, move it inside the class.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2a9a9s3.aspx ,this should help you get started

Comment: This barely looks like C#... It's Java written in C# actually. Please don't advise writing non idiomatic code. Getter/setter functions are *very* bad style in C#.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski- if it barely looks C#, why has he tagged it under C#.simply dont downvote

Comment: I was saying *your* code barely looked like C#, I removed the downvote since you edited it out.